# In GDB, using Clang & MemorySanitizer, how can I retrieve the address that triggers an error?

Tags: gdb, clang, sanitizer

I am using Clang & MemorySanitizer and got some false positives due to inline assembly.
The inline assembly code initializes some memory that is used afterwards, but the MemorySanitizer regards this as a use-of-uninitialized-value.

I am trying to write a small GDB script to filter the false positives. I put a breakpoint on __msan_warning_noreturn which is the function that prints the error in MemorySanitizer and bails. However, I couldn't find a simple way to retrieve the address which triggers the error.

How can I find the address which triggers the error?

I am working on X64 architecture, linux, clang-3.8

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The inline assembly code initializes some memory that is used afterwards, but the MemorySanitizer regards this as a use-of-uninitialized-value.

Memory Sanitizer works by instrumenting C and C++ sources. It can't (and doesn't) instrument inline assembly, so this initialization is not visible to it.

> I am trying to write a small GDB script to filter the false positives.

This is likely the wrong approach.

Instead you should use a Memory Sanitizer [blacklist](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#blacklist), or better yet, call [__msan_unpoison](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer#interface) to *tell* it that a particular memory location has been initialized.

Comment: Thanks.
In GDB I found the address of the asm instruction that initializes the code and created this breakpoint:
`break *ADDRESS
commands
    silent
    call __msan_unpoison($rsi, 8)
   continue
end`